# R: Cumulative sum with missing dates

Tags: r, cumsum

I have two dataframes, one (dataframe 1) with dates and a number of observations on each date. In the other table (dataframe 2) I have **more** dates than I have in the other dataframe.

What I would like to do is calculate the cumulative sum over dataframe 1 and place the result in dataframe 2. Any date that exists in dataframe 2, but not in dataframe 1 should simply have the value from the previous day

Dataframe 1

```
Date        Obs  
2015-01-10  2  
2015-01-11  3  
2015-01-16  1  
2015-01-20  4
```

Dataframe 2

```
Date       cumSum
2015-01-09  0
2015-01-10  2
2015-01-11  5
2015-01-12  5
2015-01-13  5
2015-01-14  5
2015-01-15  5
2015-01-16  6
2015-01-17  6
2015-01-18  6
2015-01-19  6
2015-01-20 10
2015-01-21 10
```

Please let me know if anything is unclear.
Any help would be great!

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Yes, sorry if that was unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use the devel version of `data.table` i.e. `v1.9.5` (Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

We convert the first 'data.frame' ('df1') to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), join with the 'Date' column of 'df2' using the `on` option (available in the devel version).  We create the 'Cumsum' column based on the non-NA elements  in 'Obs' by doing the cumulative sum of the 'Obs' specified by the row index in i (`!is.na(Obs)`).  Then, we can use the `na.locf` from `library(zoo)` to replace the `NA` values with the non-NA previous values and update the 'Cumsum' column.  As the 'Obs' column is not in the expected output, we can assign (`:=`) it to NULL.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
library(zoo)
res <- setDT(df1)[df2['Date'], on='Date'][!is.na(Obs), Cumsum:=cumsum(Obs)
           ][, Cumsum:=na.locf(Cumsum, na.rm=FALSE)][, Obs := NULL]
res
#         Date Cumsum
# 1: 2015-01-09     NA
# 2: 2015-01-10      2
# 3: 2015-01-11      5
# 4: 2015-01-12      5
# 5: 2015-01-13      5
# 6: 2015-01-14      5
# 7: 2015-01-15      5
# 8: 2015-01-16      6
# 9: 2015-01-17      6
#10: 2015-01-18      6
#11: 2015-01-19      6
#12: 2015-01-20     10
#13: 2015-01-21     10
```

If needed, we can replace the `NA` value in 'Cumsum' with '0'

```
res[is.na(Cumsum), Cumsum:=0]
```

Or as @Khashaa mentioned in the comments we can do this without `na.locf` by using `roll=Inf`

```
 setDT(df1)[,cumSum:=cumsum(Obs),][df2['Date'],
                       on='Date',roll=Inf][, Obs:= NULL][]
```

---

Or another option is `match` with `na.locf` to get the numeric index and replace the non-NA index (from `match`) with the cumulative sum of 'Obs', use `na.locf` as before and if needed, we can replace the `NA` with 0.

```
df2$Cumsum <- na.locf(cumsum(df1$Obs)[match(df2$Date, df1$Date)], na.rm=FALSE)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(16445, 16446, 16451, 16455),
class = "Date"), 
Obs = c(2L, 3L, 1L, 4L)), .Names = c("Date", "Obs"), 
row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <-  structure(list(Date = structure(c(16444, 16445, 16446, 16447, 
16448, 16449, 16450, 16451, 16452, 16453, 16454, 16455, 16456
), class = "Date"), cumSum = c(0L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 10L)), .Names = c("Date", "cumSum"), row.names = c(NA, 
-13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I am getting an error "unused argument (on='Date'). I have checked, my column names are both "Date", df1 is a dataframe, df2 is also a dataframe. Any ideas why this error is occurring? Thanks again!

Comment: @Mike `on` is only available in the devel version.  If you are using 1.9.4., we have to use `setkey`. i.e. setkey(setDT(df1), 'Date')`

Comment: would it then look like this: `setkey(setDT(df1)[df2['Date'], on='Date'])[!is.na(Obs), Cumsum:=cumsum(Obs)
             ][, Cumsum:=na.locf(Cumsum, na.rm=FALSE)][, Obs := NULL]`?

Comment: @Mike `setkey(setDT(df1), Date)[df2][!is.na(Obs), Cumsum:=cumsum(Obs) ][, Cumsum:=na.locf(Cumsum, na.rm=FALSE)][, Obs := NULL][]` worked for me

Comment: Amazing, works perfectly! So the setkey function just tells the function which column name to use when joining the dataframes? Thanks Akrun!!

Comment: @Mike It set the key column ie. Date and the join will be based on that common column

Comment: without resort to zoo, `df1[,cusum:=cumsum(Obs),];df1[df2, roll=Inf]`

Comment: @Khashaa That is a very nice option.  I forgot about `roll`

Comment: Ok I understand. Thanks guys, really appreciate it!